# Postgres Dropping Function in liquibase shows error

Tags: postgresql, function, liquibase

I have `FUNCTION` in xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1.0-procedures" author="api-manager">

        <sql>
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_api_consumer_audit_insert;
        </sql>

        <createProcedure>
            CREATE FUNCTION proc_api_consumer_audit_insert()
            RETURNS TRIGGER AS $api_consumer_audit$
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO api_consumer_audit(LOREM_IPSUM) VALUES(LOREM_IPSUM);
                RETURN NEW;
            END;
            $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
        </createProcedure>

        <rollback>
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_api_consumer_audit_insert;
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And liquibase during update shows me error below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:update (default-cli) on project api-manager: Error setting up or running Liquibase: Migration failed for change set db/dev/changelog/1.0/1.0-procedures.xml::1.0-procedures::api-manager:
[ERROR] Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
[ERROR] Pozycja: 55 [Failed SQL: DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_api_consumer_audit_insert]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can not resolve this error log. How should I repair this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To drop a function, you need to specify the function including the parameter signature. If the function has no parameters, you need to use `()`:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_api_consumer_audit_insert();
```

---

This has been relaxed in Postgres 10. If the function is not overloaded (so exactly one parameter signature) you can omit the parameter list. So in Postgres 10 your statement will work without changes